# Add a Grid in a matplotlib plot between different classes using a button

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, grid

I want to connect a `QPushButton` in my `QMainWindow` with a class that i created using Matplotlib so i can show a grid when i push the button. This is a part of the code:

```
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.channel = ViewWidget()

    #I add a toolbar and i put the button in here
    self.toolbar2.addWidget(self.btn_showgrid)
    self.btn_showgrid.setEnabled(True)
    self.connect(self.btn_showgrid, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.showGrid)

  def showGrid(self):
    self.btn_showgrid.setEnabled(False)
    self.channel.axes.grid(True)

class ViewWidget(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.mainWidget = QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.mainWidget.setLayout(layout)
    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas, 10)
    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
    x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)

    self.axes.plot(x,y)
```

My method called `showGrid` set the button to "disable" (is what i want to when the button is pushed) but it does not shows the grid. What am i doing wrong?

Hope you can help me. Thanks for your answers

------------------------- EDIT --------------------------------

I´ve made a few changes. I created the `QPushButton` and i added it to the toolbar of the plot.

```
# create a simple widget to extend the navigation toolbar

    self.btn_showgrid = QPushButton("Show Grid")
    self.btn_showgrid.setEnabled(True)
    self.btn_hidegrid = QPushButton("Hide Grid")
    self.btn_hidegrid.setEnabled(False)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    self.mainWidget.setLayout(layout)
    self.figure_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
    layout.addWidget(self.figure_canvas, 10)

    self.axes = self.figure_canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.axes.grid(False)

    x = np.arange(0,5,0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)

    self.axes.plot(x,y)
```

I also put a line: `self.axes.grid(False)` as you can see above. And at last i created this method:

```
def showGrid(self):
    self.btn_showgrid.setEnabled(False)
    self.btn_hidegrid.setEnabled(True)
    self.axes.grid(True)
    self.axes.draw()
```

The problem now is that when i push the button, it only hides like it should, but the grid does no show. But if create a new plot in the same `QMainWindow, it works!!!!

I think i need to refresh the plot at the moment i make `self.axes.grid(True)`, but the `draw()` does not work. How can i accomplish this? I mean, refresh the plot?

Comment: Don't you need to set the parent of your FigureCanvas? `self.figure_canvas.setParent(self.mainWidget)`

Comment: I tried that, but it does not show any change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Suever :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the canvas to re-draw.  Drawing *can* be expensive so updating the state of the artists does not trigger a re-draw (the pyplot API *does* do that but you should not use that here).  I think

```
def showGrid(self):
    self.btn_showgrid.setEnabled(False)
    self.channel.axes.grid(True)
    self.channel.canvas.draw_idle()
```

will do the trick.  The call to `draw_idle` tells Qt to, the next time it re-paints window to *also* trigger an Agg redraw for mpl, and to please schedule a repaint 'soon'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @tcaswell. See how i edited it. I use the draw() call, but it does not refresh the plot. Is there another way i could do this?

Comment: you need to call draw on the canvas, not on the axes.  Also, you should use `draw_idle` as it plays better with the Qt event loop

Comment: Thank you a lot !!!! . That was my mistake. I replace `self.axes.draw()` with `self.figure_canvas.draw_idle()`. Thank you for your answers and your help.